# How to get the nodes with degree 0 in a nx graph?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am using

```
degrees = [val for (node, val) in a.degree()]
```

I get

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

It should be : 
    [2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Basically the 4th node has a 0 degree and the function just misses it out? How do I get it to print the 4th node degree?

Comment: I edited the question. Hope that's better.

Comment: Kindly add complete example including nodes and edges you have created.

Comment: Please add code to generate your input graph network.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code should result in a `0` appearing (perhaps not in position 4 - the order may be variable) if there really is a node with degree 0.  So the error appears to be somewhere else in your code.  Please share it.